# Como saber se uma determinada "classe" esta em uso na minha pagina?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Amigos,

Existem muitas DIVs na minha pagina, preciso checar se alguma ainda nao foi "finalizada", por exemplo:

```
<div class="triagem"> conteudo a ser analizado</div>
```

as DIVs prontas ficam  com outra "class":

```
<div class="aprovada"> conteudo ja checado</div>
```

Tentei um JS mas nao funcionou pois nao tenho o elemento, ja que sao centenas e todos com ID diferentes:

```
if(.hasClass("triagem");){
   //tratamento:
}
```

outro exemplo que nao tive sucesso:

```
if(('[id^="triagem"]').classList.contains( 'triagem' ) ) {  
                 //tratamento:
            }
```

Logo, minha pergunta eh:
 como usar java pra confereir se ainda tem alguma div usando a class "triagem" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roberval, primeiro o seu html está errado, não seria isso:

```
<div class"triagem"> conteudo a ser analizado</div>
```

mas sim isso:

```
<div class="triagem"> conteudo a ser analizado</div>
```

Você pode utilizar `$('.triagem').size()`.

```
var quantidadeTriagens = $('.triagem').size();
if (quantidadeTriagens > 0){
    console.log('Ainda existem triagens');
}else{
    console.log('Não existem mais triagens, vá para casa descansar.');
}
```

`$('.triagem')` irá retornar uma lista com todos os elementos que possuem a classe triagem. A função `size` vai retornar o tamanho da lista. O resto é história, se o tamanho for `0` não tem nenhuma, se for maior que `0` existe ainda.

Comment: Ah sim...   obrigado!  foi erro de digitacao desse exemplo...  OUTRA COISA: Poderia repetir como usar o  exemplo { $('.triagem').size(). }  nao entendi?!?!  como usar com um IF por favor!

Comment: claro, vou explicar melhor.

Comment: Da uma olhada para ver se agora ficou mais claro.

Comment: Ficou bem facil de enteder!  nem sei como agradecer!!!  vou testar ja! BRIGADAO MESMO!...  outra coisa.. onde voce esta a essa hora da matina escrevendo codigo pros outros?

Comment: Estou morando na India por algum tempo, então aqui é 3PM ;)

Comment: quando voce coloca um "console.log"  no codigo... o que significa?

Comment: meu caro ... acho que to comendo bola.. pensei ter errado a digitacao.. mas ta correto..   ele sempre  retorna "0"  ou vazio.... fiz varios testes... no console por exeplo dou um "$('.memo-list-check')"   e ele retorna 2...  o que voce acha que pode ser?